# Redirect in Event receiver SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, event-receivers, redirect

My question was simple in SharePoint 2010 but in SharePoint 2013 is complicated! In 2010 I could redirect user by setting `properties.Status` and `properties.RedirectUrl`. Now `RedirectUrl` and `CancelWithRedirect` is obsolete. How can i redirect user in event receiver?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can do it only when the form, which initiates an event, is being rendered in CSRRenderMode.ServerRender mode. You also have to use Response.Redirect. You can check details in the following blog post: http://blog.sharepointalist.com/2013/03/sharepoint-2013-event-receiver-redirect.html

Answer (score -1):

In sp 2010 you can get HttpContext.Current in the event reciever constructor. Then in the event handler you can use it to call HhttpContext.Response.Redirect method.